# NSManagedObject constraints with Codable

Tags: swift, core-data, codable

My goal is to update the raw if it present in core data. I am using `codable` with `NSManagedObject` to insert raw in core data. I successfully insert and prevent duplicates entries but unable to update the row.
I want to update the recode when it shows an error. I mean to `try-catch` block.

I can do it another way by fetching a particular record with `Predicate` from `CoreData` but this way there is no point to use `CoreData` `constraints`. I can check before insert every time but I don't want to do it this way.

Check my code below, I want to do something when it throws an error while inserting duplicate recode in the catch block.

```
 func parse(_ jsonData:Data?) -> APIResult {
        do {
            guard let data = jsonData else {throw JsonError.NoData}
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let context = AppDelegate.delegate().persistentContainer.viewContext
            if let codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext = CodingUserInfoKey.context {
                decoder.userInfo[codingUserInfoKeyManagedObjectContext] = context
            }
            _ =  try decoder.decode(User.self, from: data)
            try context.save()
            return .success("")
        }catch let errror as JsonError {
            return .fail(errror.rawValue)
        }catch let error {
            return .fail(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

My Entitie where I use `email` attributes as `constraints`.

```
extension User {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<User> {
        return NSFetchRequest<User>(entityName: "User")
    }

    @NSManaged public var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged public var dob: String?
    @NSManaged public var email: String?

}
```

console Error :

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1610 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1610.)" UserInfo={NSValidationErrorObject=<NSManagedObject: 0x7fef63611dd0> (entity: User; id: 0x7fef63613eb0 <x-coredata:///User/t8C45E95D-D8C3-4900-82FA-BC313D53D5882> ; data: {
    email = "me@icloud.com";
    firstName = chandan;
    lastName = Kumar;
     dob = "20/01/1994"
}), NSValidationErrorValue=140, NSValidationErrorKey=email, NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1610.)}
```

Comment: Share error here.

Comment: *... but I don't want to do it this way.* There is no other way. To update a record you have to fetch it  – or insert a new and delete the old but this requires to fetch the (old) record, too.

Comment: @vadian Thanks we can do it this way as well as but again it's increasing the complexity by checking every time before inserting a new item. Most of the time I don't get duplicates. I want to update the raw only when it fails to save the duplicate entry. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: You could load all email values from Core Data into a Set first, then you would only need to do a fetch on those users where the json email exists in the Set.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks, It looks like a better approach.